# Error Saving the Content of an Iframe By php

Tags: php, css, iframe, save

```
var htmll = $("#iframe1").html();
alert(htmll);
$("#myTextarea")
         .val(htmll)
         .parents("form")
         .submit();
```

I am getting  the

> alert(html1);

as blank.
The location of iframe in the HTML is

```
<body>
<iframe id="iframe1" src="load.php?sinput=<?php echo $_GET['sinput'] ?>" > </iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain as the surrounding page?

Comment: Did you tried `$("#iframe1").contents();`?

Comment: Iframes dont have content that can be grabbed because of cross site scripting (XSS) rules.  Why not just load the URL and save the contents via a web scrape of some sort.

Comment: I dont know what a Web scrape is. Yes the content is on the same Domain.

Comment: @ calum - What shall i use then ?

Comment: @ish Kumar - Sir , when i used that i get the Alert as "object Object"  but still the content of the webpage being displayed

Answer (score 0):

I dunno about your JQuery code, but I know you could do something like

document.getElementById("iframe1").contentDocument.body.innerHTML

BUT, if this isn't in the same domain as the page you're executing this from, then you're going to get a security exception.

If you're trying to screen scrape, you're going to have to be more clever than that. Also, this isn't actually a PHP question.

Comment: the Frame is actually being generated from my domain itself .

Comment: I just want to save the content of the frame by any means :)    when i did the same thing for a DIV tag it worked but its not working for an Iframe